# Geo-specific Culture questions?

Tags: support

I've seen a lot of geo-specific questions get rejected in workplace, but I feel like there ought to be an appropriate place somewhere on SE to ask questions about whether an interview strategy I have might not be serving me as well in Silicon Valley/Bay Area as it has in Chicago? Are location-specific culture questions reasonable?

Answer (score 3):

This sort of confusion is precisely why Stack Exchange removed the "Too Localized" close reason, as keywords such as "city" or "location" kept setting of all kinds of alarm bells in our heads.

The key is to find the balance between a long tail problem that can't easily be found on the Internet and questions that aren't so specific to where no one else in the world will ever have that problem.  Actually, Stack Exchange was built to solve the long tail questions, as [Joel Spolsky mentions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/):

> ...we’re trying to move even more of the world’s long-tail, detailed knowledge into Stack Exchange.

As you describe it so far, I don't see anything wrong with that sort of question, as long as you're planning to ask it in Q&A format and in a way that can be answered with facts, references, or personal experience.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Also realize that most people's experience is quite limited in regards to interviewing (or working) in the same two locations in a similar industry at a similar time, so it may be difficult to get an authoritative answer.